# Building typescript frontend library

Tags: typescript, sass, rollupjs, css-modules

What I'm trying to do is build a frontend library (React components and css/scss).

**What I'm looking for:**

- Build a single commonjs `.js` file and `.css` file.
- DONT include libraries (eg.: react, etc) in the `.js` output
- Allow me to use (s)css modules

My code looks structurally like this:

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import { myComponentStyle } from './MyComponent.scss'

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className={myComponentStyle} />
  }
}
```

**MyComponent.scss**

```
.myComponentStyle { /* styles */ }
```

**MyComponent.scss.d.ts** (Generated by `typed-css-modules` to make ts compiler happy)

```
export const myComponentStyle: string;
```

And I have a single index.ts file which does export these:

**index.ts**

```
export { MyComponent } from './MyComponent.tsx'
// other components
```

If I don't have styles a rollup config like this builds this exactly the way I want:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'

const pkg = require('./package.json')

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [{ file: pkg.main, format: 'cjs', sourcemap: true }],
  external: [],
  plugins: [
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    commonjs(),
  ],
}
```

But I can't figure out how to deal with the css. I tried `rollup-plugin-postcss` and `rollup-plugin-postcss-modules` but none of them even compile.

**My question is:**

- Is there a way (example) on how to set this up with rollup?
- If not any alternatives to produce the desired single `.js` and `.css` outputs (webpack, whatever build system)?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- use `external` to exclude certain imports
- use [`rollup-plugin-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-sass) to generate a `bundle.css`.

More about Rollup `external` [here](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#external)

```
// rollup.config.js
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass'

const pkg = require('./package.json')

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [{ file: pkg.main, format: 'cjs', sourcemap: true }],
    external: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies), // OR specify an array: ['react' /* , ...etc */]
    plugins: [
        sass({
            output: 'dist/bundle.css'
        }),
        typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
        commonjs(),
    ],
}
```